# Can an attacker use his website to log user's cookies?

Tags: security

I'm learning about network security and recently learned about the Same Origin Policy. What's stopping an attacker from creating their own website and putting some javascript in their website that retrieves all the visitor's cookies (for other websites). These cookies are stored in the browser and can be retrieved using javascript or php, correct? If this is possible, what are some defenses against this (other than not visiting the user's site).

Comment: Nothing stops them, although the only cookies such an attacker will see are the ones that have been set against their own domain.  A better way to 'steal' cookies would be to use a man-in-the-middle attack to grab any cookie values that are sent in the clear (over HTTP).  Such a thing was famously done a few years back with the Gmail persistent login cookie.  Google stopped sending their cookies over plain HTTP shortly thereafter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A web server doesn't "retrieve" cookies from the browser.  When a browser sends an HTTP request to a server, it automatically includes the cookies that it has previously received *from that server's own domain*.  Sending of cookies is under the browser's control, not the server's, and browsers don't send cookies received from domain A to a server in domain B.

Comment: but if someone attach a hack to browser in form of add-in etc

Comment: Installing malware on the client is a very different scenario from a server wanting to steal cookies via HTTP.  If an attacker is able to put malware on your computer, they can design the malware to just steal your cookie database outright; there's no need to trick your browser into sending cookies to the wrong domains.